# Running Python application after UPDATE trigger in SQL Server 2014

Tags: python, sql-server, triggers

The task, when I update a column in the database table, "report" this to the Python application. Working with SQL Server is new to me, maybe I'm missing something.

The database has a trigger on the table I need. I tried to add `Exec xp_cmdshell` there, but because of this, the application that makes changes to the database hangs. In the task manager, you can see that the Python application is running, but it does not open.

After several attempts, the Python process exits and the main application reports the error "The creator of the error did not provide a reason." I ask for your help.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[OnEmployeePhotoUpdate]
ON [dbo].[EmployeePhoto]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE EmployeePhoto
    SET ModificationDateTime = GETDATE()
    WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM inserted)

    EXEC xp_cmdshell 'C:\Users\IT\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pythonw.exe D:\untitled\1.pyw'
END
```

Comment: Thats a really bad thing to be doing in a trigger. You should make your triggers run as fast as possible and do as little as possible. Normally you would insert an event into an event table and then have a service or similar which reads the events and acts on them.

Comment: Is it normal to refer to the table often? What if things don't happen often?

Comment: I don't know what you mean - sorry.

Comment: I wanted to create a trigger or event by which MY python application would display a message that there were changes.

You are suggesting to create a table with changes and validate it. Is it a good idea to access the database every 0.5 seconds?

Comment: I think you need to reconsider you entire design - certainly you do not want to be using a trigger to try and show a message to the user.

Comment: Have a look at [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server) to see if it fills your need to find out about recently modified records efficiently.

Comment: Use [Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver15) for this kind of thing